# How to tint a transparent png image in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a transparent png image with white background. Is there anyway to tint the transparent part? I tried many times but I can only tint the white background, not the transparent part. Thanks for your helps.

Update:
Many thanks to zsnow.I laid a subview below the UIImageView. Then I set color for the subview.Voila, everything is Ok.

Comment: And now, how can I save this decorating image? I just can save the transparent image, not the tinting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UIView` behind the `UIImageView` you are using and set the view's background color to the desired tint color and set the image view's background color to be transparent.

```
tintView.backgroundColor = <desired tint color>;
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just set the `alpha` to something less than done?

Comment: The `alpha` of what?  The image view?  The background view?

Comment: Woops, the image view. Image views don't have background colors that would do what you want. You could put the view on top of the image view, then set the views alpha.

Comment: He said he only wanted to tint the clear parts of the image.  Putting the tintView on top of the image view would tint the whole thing, not just the clear parts.